# Cumulative distribution function picture problem

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

[image]
this is from an past exam paper
I got for part 1: O≤X≤r = x^2*π /r^2*π
and how do I do part 2
is that right, also I don't really understand the question, when it talks about circle in the question, does it actually means within R or r

Answer (score 0):

**(i)**: We're told that $P(X \leq r) = \lambda r^2$, for some constant $\lambda$. Assuming that whoever throws the darts is skilled enough to never miss the disc entirely, we must have $P(X \leq R) = 1 = \lambda R^2$ and it follows that $\lambda = \frac{1}{R^2}$. The CDF of $X$ is thus $$
  F_X(r) = P(X \leq r) = \frac{r^2}{R^2} \text{.}
$$

**(ii)**: The score $S$ is $10 - i$ if $X$ lies within $\left(R\frac{i}{10}, R\frac{i+1}{10}\right]$ (we're not told what happens if we hit the bounds *exactly*, so whether we pick open or closed bounds is arbitrary. It won't change the result because hitting the bounds *exactly* has probability 0). It follows that $$
  P(S = 9) = P\left(\frac{R}{10} < X \leq \frac{2R}{10}\right) = F_X(\tfrac{R}{5}) - F_X(\tfrac{R}{10}) = \frac{\frac{R^2}{25} - \frac{R^2}{100}}{R^2} = \frac{3}{100} \text{.}
$$